# How to check a condition only once on datalist DataList.ItemDataBound Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a `Datalist` that has a delete button in it , I want to check if the user is admin, shows this button for each item and if not dont show that. This is my `ItemDataBound`, my problem is that for each item it connects to database and check if user is admin or not and I am worried about getting slow for large number of items. How can I fix this problem?

```
protected void GroupMembersDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
       LinkButton deletButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("DeletFromGroup");

       // here first connecet  to database to get group name  
       int GroupID = BusinessLayer.Group_Table.GetByUniqName(Page.RouteData.Values["GroupName"].ToString());
       // here connect to database and find groups admin ID and checks that are the same or not ?
       BusinessLayer.Group_Table GObject = new BusinessLayer.Group_Table(GroupID);
       if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString()) == GObject.Id)
       {
           deletButton.Visible = true;
       }
       else
       {
           deletButton.Visible = false;
       }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** solution:

```
private BusinessLayer.Group_Table GObject;
private int GroupID;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {          
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        GroupID = BusinessLayer.Group_Table.GetByUniqName(Page.RouteData.Values["GroupName"].ToString());
        GObject = new BusinessLayer.Group_Table(GroupID);
    }
    catch( Exception ee )
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set a `Session` variable and store if the user is an admin.  I'm sure you could use it on other pages as well.

Comment: @RickS its not a good idea ! for different type of users i use a session ? an admin is a user and a superAdmin is a member and admin !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize a field in the class in `Page_Load` or the `DataList`'s `DataBinding` event. Then you can access this field from `ÌtemDataBound`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int GroupID = BusinessLayer.Group_Table.GetByUniqName(Page.RouteData.Values["GroupName"].ToString());
        GObject = new BusinessLayer.Group_Table(GroupID);
        DataBindDataList(); // code that calls DataBind
    }
}

private BusinessLayer.Group_Table GObject;
```

Another way is to store this value in the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Domino: but i've posted an example. The rest is your `GroupMembersDataList_ItemDataBound` without the initialization part. But you can also use the seesion to store it.

Comment: if i put (!Ispostback) it gives me NullException if i put ouside that it cause problem ?

Comment: @Domino: where do you get the `NullReferenceException`? You should not databind the `DataList` on postback if `ViewState` is enabled(default).

Comment: it works for me ! but i am not sure its correct or not !

Comment: You can put the `BusinessLayer` code also in the `!IsPostBack` code if you don't need it somewhere else. You could also move it into the `getdata`-method if you want. But it must be executed before you call `GroupMembersDataList.DataBind();`.

Comment: I edited my answer it works Nice , but Not Sure that is correct or not :-)

Comment: i found the problem , when i press delete button to delete it get a NullReferenceException, its because for deleting it cause a post back :)